# Accept brackets correctly in bisonc++

Tags: c++, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I've tried to write a basic syntax checker using `bisonc++`

The rules are:

```
expression -> OPEN_BRACKET expression CLOSE_BRACKET
expression -> expression operator expression

operator -> PLUS
operator -> MINUS
```

If I try to run the compiled code, I get an error at this line:

```
(a+b)-(c+d)
```

The first rule is applied, the leftmost and the rightmost brackets are the `OPEN_BRACKET` and the `CLOSE_BRACKET`. The remaining `expression` is: `a+b)-(c+d`

How is it possible to prevent this behaviour? Is it possible to count the open and closed brackets?

---

**Edit**

The expression grammar:

```
expression:
    OPEN_BRACKET expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    {
        //
    }        
| operator
    {
        //
    }        
| VARIABLE
    {
        //
    }

;


operator:
    expression PLUS expression
    {
        //
    }

| expression MINUS expression
    {
        //
    }

;
```

---

**Edit2**

The lexer

```
CHAR  [a-z]
WS    [ \t\n]

%%

{CHAR}+     return Parser::VARIABLE;

"+"         return Parser::PLUS;
"-"         return Parser::MINUS;

"("         return Parser::OPEN_BRACKET;
")"         return Parser::CLOSE_BRACKET;
```

Comment: there is, but this is the relevant part only

Comment: That's what you thought the first time, and you were wrong about that. You're suppose to provide a minimal but complete example that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a normal expression grammar. Try the normal one.

```
expression
    : term
    | expression '+' term
    | expression '-' term
    ;
term
    : factor
    | term '*' factor
    | term '/' factor
    | term '%' factor
    ;
factor
    : primary
    | '-' factor // unary minus
    | primary '^' factor // exponentiation, right-associative
    ;
primary
    : identifier
    | literal
    | '(' expression ')'
    ;
```

Note also the above method of indenting and aligning, and that you only have to return `yytext[0]` from the lexer for single special characters: you don't need special token names, and it's more readable without them:

```
CHAR [a-zA-Z]
DIGIT [0-9]
WHITESPACE [ \t\r\n]
%%
{CHAR}+       { return Parser::VARIABLE; }
{DIGIT}+      { return Parser::LITERAL; }
{WHITESPACE}+ ;
.             { return yytext[0]; }
```

Comment: It's still not a normal expression grammar. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Why do you think so? This is the first time I use `bisonc` and `flex`

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel *because you're not using a normal expression grammar.* Instead, you're writing your own from scratch. Look it up. Have a look at the C expression grammar for example, and cut it down.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator rule does not look good.

Try experiment with:

```
expression:
    OPEN_BRACKET expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    {
        //
    }

|

    expression operator expression
    {
        //
    }

|

    VARIABLE
    {
        //
    }

;


operator:
    PLUS
    {
        //
    }

|

    MINUS
    {
        //
    }
;
```

As your pseudo code actually suggests...

Comment: Thank you. But the issue is with the brackets

Comment: I'm betting that the operator rule defintion is causing the inner loop and it absorbs each token...

Comment: With your operator rule I get a shift/reduce conflict